# maven dependency clash resolution

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

So when i have a dependency clash like the following:

My pom wants A, and several levels down it pulls in X version 3.0. This is the X i want.

My pom also wants B, and a few levels down it pulls in X version 2.0; which i don't want.

Version 2.0 wins, due to the default maven dependency resolution.

Note that A,B and X are 3rd party libs so i have no control over them.

Now, i've seen two ways of dealing with this:

1) Just add X version 3.0 to my pom as a dependency.
2) Add an "exclusion" to B, to exclude X.

Which is better and why? Or is it one of those "it depends"?

Comment: use exclusion as this is a good way to resolve collision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends :)

- If you need `X` for *your* code to work (you're using some of the classes from `X` in your code), then add `X` to your pom directly. By doing in such a way you clearly indicate this fact.
- If you need `X` for the *library* code to work (it is only required in runtime), then just exclude it from `B` and keep it in `A`.